# std::vector<class> fills on debug but not on release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, enums, stdvector

I have a class `A` which has several data types defined within it. Within the program, I define a vector of type `A` and then read from a text file into this vector.

When I am debugging, the vector "fills up" and I can read values from it - everything works as planned. However, when I build the release version and run the .exe, the vector is empty. The rest of the program works fine, it's just not pushing the values.

I'm fairly new to C++, so I am assuming it is something to do with my constructor function, or possibly how I handle the `enum`?. Here is my MCVE:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

enum class Type
{
    Type1
};

Type convertStringToType(std::string input)
{
    return Type::Type1;
}

class A
{
public:
    int num;
    std::string str;
    Type typ;

    A(int refNumber, std::string name, Type type)
    {
        num = refNumber;
        str = name;
        typ = type;
    }
};

std::vector<A> readFileIntoVector(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream readFile(filename);
    std::vector<A> tempVector;

    std::string tempNum = "";
    std::string tempStr = "";
    std::string tempTyp = "";

    std::getline(readFile, tempNum, ',');
    std::getline(readFile, tempStr, ',');
    std::getline(readFile, tempTyp, ',');

    while (readFile)
    {
        tempVector.push_back(A(std::stoi(tempNum), tempStr, convertStringToType(tempTyp)));

        std::getline(readFile, tempNum, ',');
        std::getline(readFile, tempStr, ',');
        std::getline(readFile, tempTyp, ',');

    }
    return tempVector;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> exampleVector = readFileIntoVector("Text.txt");

    if (exampleVector.empty() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector is empty.";
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else
    {
        int a = 1;
        do
        {
            std::cin >> a;
            if (a == 0 || a == 1)
            {
                std::cout << exampleVector.at(a).num << "\n";
                std::cout << exampleVector.at(a).str << "\n";
            }
        } while (a == 0 || a == 1);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is Text.txt:

```
1, String1, Type1,
2, String2, Type1,
```

Comment: What is in "Text.txt"? Are you sure your debug and release builds open the same file? If your debug/release builds are generated in different directories (ex. Visual Studio), in which case "Text.txt" might only be present in the debug's output directory.

Comment: I apologise if it's too long...I've no idea whether it's the int, string or enum that I need to change. I've been staring at this for a couple of days now and I'm just struggling to be honest.

Comment: Did you make sure the program can still find the text file? This matters if you are going to receive help

Comment: I do not see the check for `good` after `std::ifstream readFile(filename);`

Comment: Watch out because you're not done yet. The program will look for the file where it is run from, not where the program is. Read up on Working Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the most likely problem is that when you created a release build for the project, the text file which the program depends on was not included in the respective folder.

To fix it, you must include this file in that folder yourself, or find a way to indicate to VS that the program depends on that text file, that way it is copied to the release folder automatically for you. I don't use VS, so I don't know how possible that last part is, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

There are two possibilities:

1. As you mentioned that you are able to get correct value while debugging in debug mode,  there is a chance that you are able to read correctly from the .txt file and getting correct values in your vector, but as you are debugging in release mode you are not able to see the correct value set in the watchlist, as you may find watchlist containing garbage value in release mode even if your vector is getting the correct value.
2. You are not getting .txt file, but in that case you should not get velue even in debug version.